# Send data from Android Studio to server using url

Tags: android

I have an application created in Android Studio with API 28. I also have a php file (http: //mydomain/receptor.php) that collects data from a url of the type (http: //mydomain/receptor.php? Userid = 23 & points = 123) and saves them in the database. What I want is to know how I can send those urls from my application. I have tried different things but I can not get the application to activate the url. I do not need a response from the server in the application, I just need to activate the url. What is the easiest way to do it? Thank you!!!

Comment: can you post the code you tried with?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the code in a separate thread, paste this in your Activity Class

```
public class HTTPget extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(150000); //milliseconds
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000); // milliseconds
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            urlConnection.connect();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

And you execute the code by calling .execute() whenever you want to execute it

```
new HTTPget().execute("http://mydomain/receptor.php?Userid=23&points=123");
```

Comment: Hi. I've tried the code but it has no effect. I see "urlConnection" in gray because it is not used. It's correct like this?

Comment: Have you added internet permission to the manifest file? :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
inside <manifest> tags (not <application>)

Comment: Yes, I added internet permission

Comment: Sorry i deleted to much code when deleting read response code, you don't need. Fixed the code in the answer now.